# looping through and displaying one sprite or multiple repeating images in multiple positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm working on my new project in which I want to display kind of mozaic from around 20-30 small png images. All images will repeat themselves many times. At the end I want to get a lot of images scattered around csv shape container that move/shake a little, maybe on mouse movement.

For now I tried to loop through image sprite in javascript and change sprite position in each loop but...

I have a problem with displaying multiple positions of same sprite at same time because of overwriting variables.
Even if I will some way go through that there will be some problems with animation connected to specification of html5 canvas, I would probably have to save some properties of each image as canvas just draw and forget.
Could someone give me some tips on how to approach my problems? Maybe someone had similar project? I'm open to any suggestions and solutions.

Here is some code that I started with, It's from before I tried to mess with changing variable name through loop as it didn't brought me any closer to solution. I added some random sprite from google graphic just for sake of example (don't have original at moment).

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var sprite = new Image();
    var swidth = 260;
    var sheight = 260;

    var randomWidth = Math.random() * document.getElementById('canvas');
    var randomHeight = Math.random() * document.getElementById('canvas');

    var cx = randomWidth;
    var cy = randomHeight;
    var sx = i * 260;
    var sy = 0;
    sprite.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(sprite, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, cx, cy, 260, 213);
    };
    sprite.src = 'https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2016/05/10/how-to-create-a-sprite-sheet/spritestrip.png';
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assign a unique ID to each sprite, or in the JS handler use ```this``` so you're referring to the sprite that triggered the event. In any case, edit your question to show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: what about using CSS animation and animation-delay ? You could then  drive from javascript some CSS values switching from a class to another . If you know the ratio image and sprites number, you can also use background-size and height/width together  Here is a plain CSS example to illustrate the idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gReWRR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array, or array based list object. Javascript is very flexible with its objects and you can mix and match properties and behaviours as you need.

In the example I create a `list` object that holds a list of items, a function to add items (`list.add`), remove all items (`list.empty`), and a iterator for dealing with all items (`list.eachItem`)

Then a `spriteSheet` object that loads an image and creates a sprite sheet (cheating as I took your image and worked out the animations are related to the image size). The sprite Sheet object also creates `sprite` objects.

Then I have some objects for rendering and animating the sprites, and a prototyped object (for speed) that handles the wobble FX

Then create a sprite sheet for the walk animation (Image from Google Graphic as noted in OP's question) from the spriteSheet object called `walkSprites` that is used to create basic sprites.

Then start an animation loop, resize the canvas to fit the page and the create 100 sprites. I first create a basic sprite that only has x,y position, scale and rotation, then I add behaviour from the Wobble object.

All in the snippet. Click and hold button to give the animations a kick.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const U = undefined; 
const doFor = (count, callback) => {var i = 0; while (i < count && callback(i ++) !== true ); };
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand  = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));


const list = {
  items : null,
  add(item){ this.items.push(item); return item },
  empty(){ this.items.length = 0 },
  eachItem(callback){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
      callback(this.items[i],i);
    }
  },
}
const spriteSheet = {
  image : null,
  ready : false,
  load(URL){
    this.image = new Image;
    this.image.src = URL;
    this.image.onload = ()=>{
      const sprites = [];
      const w = this.image.width;
      const h = this.image.height;
      for(var i = 0; i < w/h; i++){
        sprites.push({x : i * h, y : 0, w : h,h : h});
      }
      this.image.sprites = sprites;
      this.ready = true;
    }
  },
  create(index,x,y,scale,rot){
     return Object.assign({},sprite,{image:this.image,index,x,y,scale,rot} );
  },
}
const sprite = {
  draw(){
    ctx.setTransform(this.scale,0,0,this.scale,this.x,this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.rot);
    const spr = this.image.sprites[this.index];
    const w = spr.w;
    const h = spr.h;
    ctx.drawImage(this.image,spr.x,spr.y,w,h,-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
  }
}
function FChase(val,accel,drag){
    this.val = val;
    this.valChase = 0;
    this.valReal = 0;
    this.accel = accel;
    this.drag = drag;
    
}
FChase.prototype = {
    update(val = this.valReal){
        this.valChase += (this.val-this.valReal) * this.accel;
        this.valChase *= this.drag;
        this.valReal += this.valChase;
        return this.valReal;
    },
    kick(amount){
        this.valChase += amount;
    },
    
}
const accel = 0.15;
const drag = 0.7;
const animSpeed = 100;
const wobble = {
    init(){
        this.xc = new FChase(this.x,accel,drag);
        this.yc = new FChase(this.y,accel,drag);
        this.rc = new FChase(this.rot,accel,drag);
        this.sc = new FChase(this.scale,accel,drag);
        this.animSpeed = rand(0.2,1.2);
        this.animOffset = rand(1);
        return this;
    },
    update(){
        this.index = (((globalTime / animSpeed) * this.animSpeed + this.animOffset * this.image.sprites.length) | 0) % this.image.sprites.length;
        this.x = this.xc.update(this.x);
        this.y = this.yc.update(this.x);
        this.scale = this.sc.update(this.scale);
        this.rot = this.rc.update(this.rot);
    },
    kick(){
        this.xc.kick(rand(-40,40));
        this.yc.kick(rand(-40,40));
       // this.sc.kick(rand(-0.1,0.1));
        this.rc.kick(rand(-1,1));
    }
}
// create a sprite sheet and load media
const walkSprites = Object.assign({},spriteSheet);
walkSprites.load("https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2016/05/10/how-to-create-a-sprite-sheet/spritestrip.png");

// create a list for the sprites.
const spriteList = Object.assign({},list,{items:[]});  

// create 100 sprites
const spriteCount = 100;
function createSprites(){
  spriteList.empty();
  doFor(spriteCount,i=>{
    var spr = spriteList.add(
      walkSprites.create(
        randI(6),  // image may not have loaded, but I know how many sprites there are
        randI(canvas.width ), // pos
        randI(canvas.height),
        rand(0.25,0.5), // scale
        rand(Math.PI*2), // rotation
      )
    );
    spr = Object.assign(spr,wobble).init();
  })
}
// use requestAnimationFrame to animate
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;
var frameCount = 0;
// main update function
function update(timer){
    globalTime = timer;
    frameCount += 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
      cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
      ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
      createSprites();
    }else{
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    if(walkSprites.ready){
        if(mouse.button){
            spriteList.eachItem((sprite,i)=>{
              if(frameCount % 20 === i % 20){
                sprite.kick()
              }
            });
        }
        spriteList.eachItem(sprite=>sprite.update());
        spriteList.eachItem(sprite=>sprite.draw());
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas, span{ position : absolute; top : 0px; left 0px; }
span {
  z-index:10;
  font-family:arial black;
  font-size:34px;
  color : yellow;
 }
```

```html
<span >CLICK HOLD to KICK animations</span>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, You totally made my day!!